# Removing "read" logic from gmail script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am fairly new to google app scripts and hoped you could help me…  I am sure this is an easy question.

I am running the following script to archive old emails.  It currently only archives read emails, but I would like to have it archive messages with these labels regardless of whether they are read or unread.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
function archiveInbox4() {
// Every thread in your Inbox that is read, older than fourteen days, and not labeled "delete me".    
var threads = GmailApp.search('label: inbox older_than:14d label:"Calendar"|"wacuho-acuho-i"|"professional-organizations"');    
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].moveToArchive();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way that you can mark emails read first then archive them as read emails.

Sample code is like:

```
function markArchivedAsRead() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:unread -label:inbox');
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
};
```

However this operation can only be applied to at most 100 threads. To fix this, you have to manually do a search for `"is:unread"` and mark all of them as read before running the script, so that it starts with a clean slate. The script can only process 100 threads per run, so if you give it more than 100 on the first run, that'll obviously bust it. See the reference [link](http://mikecr.it/ramblings/marking-gmail-read-with-apps-script#comment-891201612).

You can also have this code to get it done by google apps script:

```
function markArchivedAsRead() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    GmailApp.markThreadRead(threads[i]);
    }
};
```